# allow zero numbers with REGEx

Tags: regex

I have a Regexp which works well for positive numbers but want it to work also when the user just inputs 0 how can this be done? I tried to learn how to do it but without any success so far

Regexp: `^(?!(?:0|0\.0|0\.00)$)[+]?\d+(\.\d|\.\d[0-9])?$`

Edit I'm sorry for maybe not being clear enough

I want it to accept all positive values to 2 decimal places but I also want it to accept only the number zero

like: 
0
0.0
0.00
1.25
1.2
and doesn't accept anything under -0.01

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: @NirMH It should not really matter.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac - From the regex tag info description: "remember [to] include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex

Comment: @Kobi I stand corrected. Thanks for telling me, mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirements I came up with this:

`^\+?\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`

Is it what you are looking for?

The above regular expression matches all positive decimals to two decimal places with or without the '+' symbol or a leading integer, the following are some sample mismatch cases.

1.324
3.
-23.1

Comment: Theres an issue with this, the expression allows "nothing" to be matched, quickfix: remove the ability to match decimals written like `.32` by changing the `*` to a `+`

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove your negative lookahead:

```
^[+]?\d+(\.\d\d?)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem because of the negative lookahead, take a look at [this](http://regexr.com/38smn):

```
[+]?\d+(\.\d|\.\d[0-9])?
```

But you could further simplify it like [so](http://regexr.com/38smq):

```
(?:\d*\.)?\d+
```

Answer (score -1):

`^-?[0-9]+$` if you want to force `-` for negative but not `+` for positive.

`^-?[0-9]+.?[0-9]*$` for decimal fraction as well.